# Accessing array from objects method within array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, canvas, methods

I have researched this question but cannot find an answer. I am new to JavaScript arrays and method scope.

I have a circles array which contains Circle Object. This has an update method which ultimately lets it draw itself to the canvas and move

Problem is the Circles need to be able to access the location of other Circles in their circles array to see if they've collided.

But when I use the Circles method they don't recognise their holding array - circles:

```
let circles;

function init() {
    circles = [];

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let dy = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 8;
    let radius = Math.random() * 30;
    let color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    let x = Math.random() * (innerWidth - radius * 2) + radius;
    let dx = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 8;
    let y = Math.random() * (innerHeight - radius * 2) + radius;

    circles.push(new Circle(x, y, dx, dy, radius, color));
}
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    c.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
    circles.forEach(circle => {
        circle.update();
    });
}

function Circle(x, y, dy, dx, radius, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.dy = dy;
    this.dx = dx;
    this.radius = radius;
this.color = color;

this.update = function (circles) {
    for (i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
        if (this === circles[i]) {
            continue;
        }
        if (getDistance(this.x, this.y, circles[i].x, circles[i].y) - radius * 2 < 0) {
            console.log('TOUCH')
        }
    }
    this.draw();
}

this.draw = function () {
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    // c.strokeStyle = 'black';
    c.fillStyle = this.color;
    c.fill();
    c.closePath();
}
}
```

This function leads to error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Because it doesn't recognise the circles array.

How can I give my objects method access to the array the objects in?

Comment: remove `circles` from `this.update = function (circles) {`. It's defining a new variabe circles for that local function scope, rather than using the original. Additionally you might want to use var rather than let for scoping reasons but not 100% on that top of my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `update` method on `Circle` expects a `circles` array to be passed, but you're not passing anything:

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    c.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);
    circles.forEach(circle => {
        circle.update(circles); // <--- HERE
    });
}
```